# Writing : Would you quit killing after how many people you would kill?

Tags: writing, will-would, who-whom

A : Would you quit killing after how many people you would kill ?

B : I would quit killing after I would kill five more.

(or I would quit after I will make the number 10, which is the number of peoples I killed)

I want to know A's question so that B replies like the above.

**[Add]** Following Bruce Murray's comment, I found the sentence

> How many people will you stop killing after you kill them ?

**Is this a correct sentence ?**

**[Add2]** A : How old do you think he is ?

B : (I think that) he is around 20.

The first sentence in the dialogue inspires me this question.

I think I would stop killing after I kill 10 people.

From this sentence we can make asking :

A : **How many do you think you would stop killing after you kill ?**

B : Maybe 10 people.

> Here is A's asking correct ??

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is incomprehensible.

Comment: Sentence **A** does not make any sense. I mean, I can imagine what the speaker wants to say but it's totally mangled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would you quit killing after how many people you would kill ?

This is confusing because starting a sentence with "Would you" means you are looking for either a yes/no answer or a choice among options provided.

> Would you like to go the movies?
> Would  your rather have pizza or hamburgers for dinner?

But you are looking for a numeric response, so starting with "would you" doesn't make sense. You need to use a prompt that asks for a number or an amount.

> I understand you want revenge for your brother's death, but *how many people* do you have to kill before you stop?